# Invalid Website URL value, email format expected SagePay Intergration Kit

Tags: opayo

I'm attempting to use SagePay's Server Intergration PHP Kit, but on installation I'm getting the error Warning: Invalid Website URL value, email format expected this is in /lib/classes/settings.php on line 1127, all I've done to edit the kit is enter the database details that I have set up

any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

For quick fix this issue you can add url of your test site into sagedemo/lib/classes/settings.php in public function setWebsite($website) like this:

```
public function setWebsite($website)
{
    $website = 'http://sagepayintegrationkit.dev/';
    if (!empty($website) && SagepayValid::url($website))
    {
        $this->_website = $website;
    }
    else
    {
        trigger_error("Invalid Website URL value, email format expected, '" . $website . "' given", E_USER_WARNING);
    }
}
```

It works form but it looks like banal crutch :)